# asp.net web service using #angularjs

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, angularjs

how to solving problem  Control-Allow-Origin in #angularjs

[image]

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. please include code, error messages, and other _text-based_ information ***as text***, [not as screenshot](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).
 i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Either change the port in your .net API settings file, or change the port in the path where you compose your request (the Angular app), as the message states, you do have a CORS policy in place, it just doesn't match the request path. The ports are different. Make sure to also match  the protocol, http vs https may also invalidate the request and, of course, you should use the secure protocol.